# MSI package with *.ini file

Tags: windows-installer

I would like to create MSI file from *.exe file. My *.exe file updates language for printer driver. If I simply start .exe - it wants - select language and so on. I converted exe to msi, using /VERYSILENT parameter but it reports error - error no language specified.  How can i put exe and ini file - with language specification to one MSI package?

Sorry for "not so clever" question

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The ini file is just a file. You can add it in the same way as you do with the exe.

Comment: But ive used  exe to msi converter :)  which command shall i use, if i would  put them both?

Comment: You probably use the wrong tool. Use Windows-Installer tools like setup-and-deployment project in visual studio or WiX. The later requires some skills in XML and knowledge about Windows Installer.